# como puedo redireccionar a una ruta

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

buenas quiero que al hacerle clic en un boton me redireccione a otra pestaña usando laravel con la tecnologia blade

```
Route::get('home', function() {
    return view('onepage.home');
});
```

es mi ruta.!

```
<ul>
    <li><a  href =" ">how it works</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Probaste con '<a href="{{ url('home') }}">how it works</a> ?

Answer (score 3):

Una forma seria poniendo el enlace

```
<a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
```

Otra forma seria seria si tienes un controlador `resource` seria

```
<a href="route('usuario.create') }}">Crear usuario</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo recomendaría que le dieras un alias a tu ruta con el método `name()` ya que si ahorita tu ruta se llama "home" pero después quieres que se llame "inicio", no tendrías que cambiar absolutamente ningún archivo más que el de rutas.

```
Route::get('home', function() {
    return view('onepage.home');
})->name('home');
```

Para obtener la ruta con alias se usa el método `route()`

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">how it works</a></li>
</ul>
```

Si después quieres que tu url se llame "inicio" sólo tendrías que cambiar el archivo de tus rutas:

```
Route::get('inicio', function() {
        return view('onepage.home');
    })->name('home');
```

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a  href ="{{ url('/home') }} target="_blank">how it works</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Asignando un nombre a la ruta:

```
Route::get('home', function() {
     return view('onepage.home');
})->name('home');

<ul>
   <li>
      <a  href ="{{ route('home') }} target="_blank">how it works</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

`taget="_blank"` es para abrir la url en otra pestaña del navegador (mencionaste pestaña). Si no te refieres a "otra pestaña" del navegador, solo hay que quitar `taget="_blank"`